# Modifying a type to contain the static values of an object instead of their derived types ( { test: 3 } instead of { test: number })

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to create a color palette, and I want to export an object with all my colors attached, and get their typing information. Since each key can only be one value I was hoping that their type would be exported as that specific value. However, when I simply export the set of colors every key is turned into a string (instead of the specific value).

```
 export const red = "#FF0000";
 export const tuna = "#36393F";

 export default {
  red,
  tuna
 };
```

If I do the following I get what I want. However, I would have to manually add to the type every-time I add a color.

```
 export const red = "#FF0000";
 export const tuna = "#36393F";

 type enumInterface = {
   tuna: typeof tuna;
   red: typeof red;
 };
 const defaultExport: enumInterface = {
   tuna,
   red
 };
 // When I import this in another file the typing information 
 // shows the hexcode instead of type string. which is what I want
 export default {
  ...defaultExport
 };
```

I know about mapping types, so I would hope to do something like this, but it doesn't work, because T[P] is not a value but a type.

```
type testInterface<T> = {
  [P in keyof T] : typeof T[P];
}
```

I'm hoping someone would know how to achieve a similar effect as the second set but using mapping types so I don't have to type out every type. Thank you for any help you can be!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution to get the literal type is to just use a type assertion:

```
const defaultExport = {
    tuna: "#36393F" as "#36393F",
    red: "#FF0000" as "#FF0000"
};
```

If you are going to use this pattern several times (or have many enum members), you could create a helper class to aide in building the enum.

```
class EnumBuilder<T = {}> {
    private allValues: any;
    end(): { [P in keyof T] : T[P]} {
        return this.allValues;
    }
    add<TKey extends string, TValue extends string>(key: TKey, value: TValue): EnumBuilder<T & { [P in TKey]: TValue }>{
        this.allValues[key] = value;
        return this as any;
    }
}

const defaultExport = new EnumBuilder()
    .add('red', "#FF0000")
    .add('tuna', "#36393F")
.end();

export default {
    ...defaultExport
};
```